# Intellij idea Stop execution of a function without stopping full debugging

Tags: debugging, grails, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4 to debug a Grails application. It takes around 2 minutes for me to start a debugging session. I want to avoid restarting as much as possible.

I am trying to debug a controller action and I need to see that it gets hit. It performs some action which I don't want to perform. I know that this can be performed by putting a return in that action in first line temporarily. But was thinking that in general, all frameworks do not support code changes on the fly. So does IDEA have any feature which allows me to simply exit from a debug point without exiting the whole debug (i.e. exit from a single HTTP request without canceling the entire debugger session)?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by evaluating "System.exit(0)" using the Alt-F8 (Evaluate Expression) dialog.

Comment: It terminates whole server in spring.